# How to avoid screen flickering?

Tags: c#, winforms, flicker

I am making a windows form application and mainly my screen is divided between 3 parts like

```
===========================================================================
                    Top panel (it doesn't flicker)
===========================================================================
||         || 'it has a panel & panel contains a table layout,this tabble layout'
||         || 'has a picture box and a label, picture & text of label is'           
||         ||'changed on the click of side bar menu' (PROB: this flickers a lot)
||side bar ||==============================================================
||(doesn't ||'this part also has a panel and panel contains different table'
||flicker) ||'layouts and on the click of a menu, related table layout is shown and'  
||         ||'some of the parts of table layout are created dynamically.'
||         ||           
||         ||                (PROB: this flickers a lot)
||         ||
```

i searched a lot and found this solution everywhere and i tried this

```
public constructor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                      ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                      ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
                      ControlStyles.ContainerControl |
                      ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                      ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor
                      , true);
    }
```

i also tried this

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
get
{
CreateParams handleParam = base.CreateParams;
handleParam.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;   // WS_EX_COMPOSITED       
return handleParam;
}
}
```

it changes the whole background of my screen to black color.

but still problem remains the same, can someone tell me how to solve this problem and where i am doing mistake ?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Screens don't flicker without updates. So please show us the code that repeatedly updates the flickering part.

Comment: What controls types are the ones that flicker?  What are you doing with these problem controls?  EG: Loading 100,000 records for display, etc...

Comment: What do you do with this Form? I mean: At which action does it flicker? If you make a WinForm with, say, 3 such areas as Panels and put some Controls into those Panels, it shouldn't flicker at all. Neither on clicking on the Panels nor by dragging the window.

Comment: In your solution attempt code: this.DoubleBuffered = true; and DoubleBuffered = true; does the same. Same to the SetStyle-calls. Because "this" explicitly references the local scope (at least in this code snipped). If you double call such things at other places in your code and set and unset certain values fast, this can produce flickering, too.

(After OPs added new code snippet:) You still should tell us what happens within your PROB-areas. (Are these userControls? PictureBoxes? Are you drawing on their background (with OnPaint)?)

Comment: not from here. a classic is say blue background, clear to black, and then repaint to blue. or clear off all the controls and then dynamically reinstantiate them. So unneccessary paints

Comment: there was something I did (but its been about 4 years now...) that stopped the screen layout from updating until after I completed my work... I think it was something like "SuspendLayout()" and "ResumeLayout()"... you may want to look into it.

Comment: before you show `what you have tried`, we need to see `what causes the problem` and `when does it happen`

Comment: I don't think it will fix your issue, but after calling SetStyle() you should call UpdateStyles(): `this.UpdateStyles();`  Definitely give us more details about what is inside these panels and how you interact with them...

Comment: @Justin please see the updated part of my question(text in red color).

Comment: @Michael please see the updated part of my question (text in red color)

Comment: @RichardB i tried suspendlayout and resumelayout but it's not working, please see the updated part of my question(text in red color)

Comment: Then please specifiy what you do in the side bar click event (or what method you call and what that method does) and specify, what the manual or automatic triggers (= other methods like layout updaters or data updaters) do with your flickering panels.

Comment: on the side bar click event i show(visible=true) a particular panel in center and that panel contains a table layout and controls in that table layout are created dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more to go on, my gut says that you are either adding a lot of data do those areas or there is a lot of resizing going on.

try this anywhere you update the screen ( adding rows to listviews/boxes/etc ) or resize the screen, or anything else that will cause the screen to redraw. 
ex:

```
public void something_resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.SuspendLayout(); 

        // Do your update, add data, redraw, w/e. 
        // Also add to ListViews and Boxes etc in Batches if you can, not item by item.  
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        this.ResumeLayout(); 
    }
}
```

Its important to put the ResumeLayout() call in the finally block, because if an exception occurs for w/e reason, you want your window to layout, regardless of what you do with the exception.

Comment: i tried this but it's not working..can you tell me what can be the cause behind this ?

Comment: yes finally it worked. i don't know why it was not working before.